# Error when I compile the web form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I found that there is an error showing a different version of script.

The first line of script in Login1.aspx under my project PRJ should be

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Light.master" CodeBehind="Login1.aspx.cs"  Inherits="PRJ.Login1" %>
```

However,

the error show a wrong script in the Inherits properties when I compiled the webform project PRJ.

I have tried to rebuild the project and solution, but it doesn't work.

How can I fix this problem? Please help!!

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Project.Account.Login1'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Light.master" CodeBehind="Login1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project.Account.Login1" %>
Line 2:  <%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v14.1, Version=14.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxx" Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors" TagPrefix="dx" %>
Line 3:  

Source File: /Account/Login1.aspx    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18446
```

Comment: It looks like this class doesn't exist `Project.Account.Login1` and you said that should be `PRJ.Login1`. Just change in the Login1.aspx the first line pointing the right class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to the error in Visual Studio.
After restarting the visual studio, it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

For Code behind attribute you have to give page behind class name like :
CodeBehind="Login1.aspx.cs".

And For Inherits we have to give complete path with namespace like : 
Inherits="YourNameSpace.Login1".